# I want to passing value to icewarp with base64 encoded. Do Icewarp need decoded script?

Tags: variables, base64

Currently my job is to hide the username and password from being displayed when we passing the value to icewarp webmail. The previous developer passing the value like below :

```
Header("refresh:0;url=http://sample-icewarp.com/webmail/index.html?!#$username:$password");
```

and it redirect user to icewarp webmail, but with username and password displayed on address bar for split seconds. But on slow connection, it give enough time to read and memorize it.

I am planning to work with base64 encoding. But i am confuse, do i need to make icewarp decode as well?

I am not programming expert, working as IT technical support. This has become my part of job.

From googling, i found this sample code of base64 encoding :

```
$data = /* some data */;
$base64Data = base64_encode($data);
$urlData = urlencode($base64Data);
$htmlData = htmlspecialchars($urlData);
printf('<input type="hidden" value="%s" name="pass-it-on">', $htmlData);
```

How do i edit this thing to make it redirect to icewarp webmail?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use external login (see icewarp/html/webmail/client/_external)? It would use AFAIK the RSA login icewarp has. Or SSO...